# Filter elements in for

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the next command that returns the following output

`kubectl get pods`

**Output:**

```
NAME                                      READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
svc-admin-async-6d4cd4989f-8lzcq          1/1     Running            0          4d7h
svc-admin-c795b488d-kpcsn                 1/1     Running            0          3d2h
svc-admin-c795b488d-m9mjg                 1/1     Running            0          7d6h
svc-bpm-inbox-77fffc4d89-cx7g7            1/1     Running            0          7d6h
svc-bpm-tasks-654695689d-spvt7            1/1     Running            0          3d17h
svc-bpm-tasks-654695689d-wrclq            1/1     Running            0          3d17h
svc-claim-78b7d8db99-9m6zs                1/1     Running            0          120m
svc-claim-78b7d8db99-qvq9m                1/1     Running            0          120m
```

I need to list only pods that starts with a given parameter. For example, if the param is svc-bpm-tasks, only should to show:

```
svc-bpm-tasks-654695689d-spvt7
svc-bpm-tasks-654695689d-wrclq
```

I have the following script, but I dont know how to filter:

```
set param_to_filter=%~1

FOR /F "skip=1" %%I in ('kubectl get pods') DO (
    :: if %%I starts_with param_to_filter
    echo %%I
)
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FOR /F %%I in ('kubectl get pods^|findstr /i /b /L /C:"%~1"') DO (
```

should do what you want.

The caret escapes the pipe, telling `cmd` that the pipe is part of the command to be executed.

`findstr` finds any string that `/b` begins with the string `%~1`, which is the first parameter to the batch.

The `skip` is no longer needed as the header line would not start with any of the target strings.

The `/i` is optional, making the match case-insensitive.

! Do not use `::` comments in a `code block` (parenthesised sequence of lines) as it's actually a broken label, which confuses `cmd`. Use `rem` in code blocks.

Amended - Since any string may be used for `%1`, using `/L` to specify `L`iteral comparison to override the default `/r` (regex match)

The `/c:"string"` match also compensates for the possibility of a space in the string `%~1`. If a space appears in `%~1` (by supplying a quoted parameter `"one two"`) then without the `/c:`, `findstr` would search for `one` OR `two`. With `/c:`, the search is for **one<kbd>Space</kbd>two**.

Comment: @Compo : You could be right - I'll do a few experiments.

Comment: @Compo : true, I'll modify the post to use `/l c:` but it would appear that `-` is used in `/r` mode to specify a character-range and the expression would then be in `[..]`